Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention', version: '0.5.0'] was not found. Error while running android build in react native
While running "npm run android" command in terminal it shows the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\bssin\appDevelopment\AwesomeApp\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\settings.gradle.kts' line: 16

What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention', version: '0.5.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:



Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention:org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention.gradle.plugin:0.5.0')
Searched in the following repositories:
MavenRepo
Google
Gradle Central Plugin Repository.

I am using a windows 11 pc. Earlier for react-native version 0.73 it was working fine but while initializing a new project with latest version this time shows this error. I tried removing node_modules and reinstalling them. Also I tried starting a new project with lower version, still shows the same error.
What is the issue? Please help me fix this.

If you are encountering this error on React Native 0.73.x,
Update Gradle to 8.x.
Modify file android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties as follows:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
React Native Upgrade Helper
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.72.14&to=0.73.0#RnDiffApp-android-gradle-wrapper-gradle-wrapper.properties
OR
React native Issue:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42149
May be Relevant Issue
Can't create build for android cause of this issue: Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention', version: '0.5.0'] was not found

Had the same problem. It was http proxy ports.
this can help

https://dev.to/leofolive/setup-macbook-m1-for-react-native-development-4ca7
How to remove JVM property "https.proxyHost"?

Here is what worked for me, just write in terminal
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DsocksProxyPort"

check proxy settings
open android studio => reset android studio caches, you can also install plagin "gradle utilities" (there you can clear gradle caches)

